What could be the cause of this strange white blob that seems to be captured in my photo?
I need some opinions related to this photo:

First of all, to give a bit of context, the photo was taken with Google Pixel 4a and had HDR stabilization on activated by default. Also, the light was powerful in that room from the left side and the environment was full with dust particles.
When the photo was taken, no items were near the leg, but somehow the camera lens captured that white thingy in the left side. I started to investigate a bit because I wanted to figure out what camera error could do this. From my investigation, the white shape is most likely an artifact introduced by HDR and digital stabilization attempting to compensate for movement.
Do you know if this error is common and could lead to this white error artifact? Do you have any other example of photos with this kind of error?

Can you show the full thingy or was it cut by the image border? Also, when you have dust particles near the lens with a strong light they can show as "orbs" in the shot (and then be "enhanced" by whatever processing/butchering is done in the camera).

@xenoid thanks a lot for the reply, sure here is the link with the full picture https://imgur.com/a/E7z4sji
So do you think that white artifact may be an "orbs"?
Also, do you know is this a common problem? to have generated this kind of orbs?
Have you seen photos with the same or similar error?

This kind of thing does not occur without sudden and strong changes in light or without the camera moving during the photo shoot.  So the Pixel camera doesn't create anything new from nothing.  If this is a non-recurring situation, there's not much we can say about this.
